# Azure SQL server set Allow access to Azure services in an ARM template or PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure

I need to set this setting using an ARM template or in Powershell.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Power Shell, you could use [`New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/new-azuresqldatabaseserverfirewallrule?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) to set this.

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName "lpqd0zbr8y" -AllowAllAzureServices
```

For template, you could template like below:

```
   {

            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules",
            "kind": "v12.0",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_shui_name'), '/', parameters('firewallRules_AllowAllAzureServices_name'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
            "location": "South Central US",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_shui_name'))]"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: thanks very much for that. Great info. I assume the 0.0.0.0 is a trick to get the Allow access to Azure service button set to yes? Otherwise  0.0.0.0 => 0.0.0.0 says to me, that no one will have access! :)

Comment: @RuSs did you figure how to set it to be turned OFF by default from the ARM template?

Comment: @Franky_frankly Modify `startIpAddress` and `endIpAddress` to `255.255.255.255`, your template will set it to be turned OFF. I had answer your question, you could check.

Comment: @Franky_frankly this question was answered in the answer

Comment: This is documented. Please follow link `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2015-05-01-preview/servers/firewallrules`

Comment: _The start IP address of the firewall rule. Must be IPv4 format. Use value '0.0.0.0' for all Azure-internal IP addresses._ from [ServerFirewallRuleProperties](The start IP address of the firewall rule. Must be IPv4 format. Use value '0.0.0.0' for all Azure-internal IP addresses.)